# Is HPE Loadrunner a java application?

Tags: java, performance-testing, loadrunner

I wanted to use a performance testing tool for an application.
Had to choose between Jmeter or Loadrunner.

Jmeter being a java application would help me a lot as I am familiar with java programming, but just wanted to know if Loadrunner is also based on java?

Comment: Is it a problem that tool for performance testing is not related with your progamming language?

Comment: There is plenty of [good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_LoadRunner#Scripting_Languages) documentation and [resources](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/index.html) about LoadRunner out there - you don't really need to ask here to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

> HPE LoadRunner client emulation scripts are usually created using the
>   ANSI C programming language. However, Java and .Net programs can also
>   be run by HPE LoadRunner. Version 12.50 added the use of JavaScript
>   for Web-HTTP/HTML scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Java virtual user support was added in LoadRunner version 6 and has been available in every release for the past 16 years.

You also may want to consult the documentation available here

http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/tocs/164750_toc_creating_scripts_with_VS.htm

There are some interesting items of note if you would prefer to develop your virtual users in Eclipse or Visual Studio instead of the Virtual User Generator